# Uncaught (in promise) BigNumber Error for address

Tags: solidity

I have a function in ERC721 contract which returns an address.

I am passing the returned address to ERC20 transferFrom function, and getting the following error.
[image]

My javascript code

```
Voting.deployed().then(function(ERC20Instance) {
      let buyerAddress = $("#to-address").val();
      ERC20Instance.approve(buyerAddress, 100, {gas: 1000000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]});
      ERC20Instance.transferFrom(buyerAddress, contractInstance.getCreator(), 10, {gas: 1000000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]});
^^^^This line is causing an error. 
    })
```

and ERC721 contract:

```
    function getCreator() public view returns (address) {
        return nftInfo[owner].creator;
    }

    function mint(string calldata nftName) external payable {
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        
        owner = msg.sender;
        nftInfo[msg.sender].nftId = newItemId;
        nftInfo[msg.sender].name = nftName;
        nftInfo[msg.sender].creator = msg.sender;

        allValidTokenIndex[newItemId] = allValidTokenIds.length;
        allValidTokenIds.push(newItemId);
        _tokenIds.increment();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
contractInstance.getCreator()
```

This JS function returns a `Promise` - not the actual address. You need to resolve the Promise first to get the address.

Same goes with the `approve()` function. You should wait until the function has been processed (i.e. after the JS Promise has been resolved) to prevent unexpected behavior resulting from the `transferFrom()` being executed asynchronously before the `approve()` finishes running.

```
Voting.deployed().then(async function(ERC20Instance) { // add `async`
    let buyerAddress = $("#to-address").val();
    await ERC20Instance.approve( // recommended: add `await`
        buyerAddress,
        100,
        {gas: 1000000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}
    );
    await ERC20Instance.transferFrom( // recommended: add `await`
        buyerAddress,
        await contractInstance.getCreator(), // add `await`
        10,
        {gas: 1000000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}
    );
```